# The Hilbert norms of KRR solutions

Tags: least-squares, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Assume that we solve a kernel ridge regression problem for data set $X$ of size $n$
$$
\hat{g} = \mathrm{arg} \min_g \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - g(x_i))^2 + ||g||^2_{\mathcal{H}}
$$
and for extended dataset $X_*$ of size $n+m$, that includes $X$
$$
\hat{g}_* = \mathrm{arg} \min_g \sum_{i=1}^{n+m}(y_i - g(x_i))^2 + ||g||^2_{\mathcal{H}}
$$
How to prove that?
$$
||\hat{g}||^2_{\mathcal{H}} \leq || \hat{g}_*||^2_{\mathcal{H}}
$$

Comment: Are $y,x$ related to $g$? How?

Comment: It was a typo. The $g$ is an estimator of true function $y = f(x)$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(y-g)^2$?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've already corrected